# Consumir endpoint rest api C# httpclient

Tags: c#, rest

Estoy intentando consumir un endpoint y tengo problemas, es raro porque solo cuando llamo a este me da error:

Todos los endpoint POST necesitan un token, que se lo agrego así en cada llamada:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Token {token}");
```

Y funcionan perfecto. Un endpoint en particular me da este error y supongo a que no se refiere al token que ya tengo:

> "detail": "Las credenciales de autenticación no se proveyeron."

En PostMan me da exactamente el mismo error...
Este es mi código C#:

```
string token = await GetTokenAsync();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Token {token}");
HttpContent response = (await _httpClient
   .PostAsync($"api/v1/resources/parts/{Id}/regenerate_sftp/", null)).Content;
string body = await response.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic obj = JsonNode.Parse(body).AsObject();
return (string)obj["new_sftp"];
```

UPDATE:

Este es el endpoint:
[image: foto]

Comment: Primero prueba desde postman y luego en c#, en `Authorization", $"Token` intenta cambiar por `Authorization", $"Bearer` y estas haciendo.un post y enviando datos null, no sera un metodo `GET`?

Comment: Los endpoints que necesitan token funciona bien. Es este endpoint el que me está dando problemas.  Tengo el mismo error en Postman, lo raro es que tengo acceso al sitio  en donde los usuario consiguen la clave del ftp y con F12 tampoco puedo llegar a la solución.

Comment: @Daniel este es el endpoint que necesito: https://prnt.sc/26g4mxz

Comment: a lo que veo en tu foto, no es necesario un token, el unico campo requerido es el id, hay alguna manera de que puedes compartir el acceso para hacer las pruebas, la uRL completa y si es necesario un token

Comment: @Daniel Sí necesita token pero en el header, en la foto no se visualiza pero para entrar a esos endpoints en swagger hay que logearse con user y password.

Comment: Este es el link PostMan: [enlace] (https://www.getpostman.com/collections/2d57bcfb9b7ebc27ca6a)

Comment: No es posible usar CSRF en .Net Fuente:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639895/17223896)